# How to create a packages in Laravel5.0?

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I'm create an printing packages with many kind of slips in laravel 5.0 but I can't done because I got errors 500 when i refresh my website

Issue: when I add **'print\slips\PrintServiceProvider',** to app.php i will get 500 errors on my web application and In PrintServiceProvider can't use **Print\Slips;** as namespace.

Step 1:
      I have created packages directories like this in Root folder:

```
   packages/print/slips/src
   packages/print/slips/src/config/print.php
   packages/print/slips/src/PrintController.php
   packages/print/slips/src/printServiceProvider.php
   packages/print/slips/src/rout.php
   packages/print/slips/composer.json
```

Step2: 
     I have added an array element for app.php in **app/config/app.php** on **Autoloaded Service Providers**
    'providers'=>[
         //Default of Laravel services,
         'print\slips\PrintServiceProvider',
       ]

Step3: 
     I have create array in composer.

```
    {
  "name": "Print\Slips",
  "description": "I want to create package fro print slips which the easies way to user with another projects ",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Printing Services",
      "email": "example@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "illuminate/support": "5.0.*"
  },
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Print\Slips": "packages/print/slips/src/"
    }
  }
 }
```

Step 4:

In PrintServiceProvider

```
<?php
namespace Print\Slips;// Errors happend 

use IlluminateSupportServiceProvider;

class PrintServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->publishes([__DIR__.'/config/print.php' => config_path('print.php')]);
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you used artisan to generate your service (I would guess not), have you tried `php artisan make:provider PrintServiceProvider` check docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/providers

Comment: what happen if not use artisan and menus?